# GRUB loader not working w/ Kali Linux Dual Boot

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I have tried to install Kali Linux dual boot following [this tutorial](https://techlog360.com/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-v2-0-with-windows-10/).

I followed all the instructions and everything worked perfectly.

The only problem was step 25 when after restarting the computer and removing the memory card GRUB loader doesn't appear to let me choose what operational system I would like to run.

Could you help me to fix this problem?